# String Array Searching

Tags: c#, arrays, logic

I had an interview for a Jr. developer position a few days ago, and they asked:

"If you had an array of letters "a" and "b" how would you write a method to count how many instances of those letters are in the array?"

I said that you would have a `for loop` with an `if else` statement that would increment 1 of 2 counter variables. After that, though, they asked how I would solve that same problem, if the array could contain any letter of the alphabet. I said that I would go about it the same way, with a long `IF` statement, or a `switch` statement. In hindsight, that doesn't seem so efficient; is there an easier way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare the array of size 256 (number of possible character codes) zero it and simply increase the one which corresponds to a char code you read.

For example if you are reading the 'a' the corresponding code is ASCII 97 so you increase the array[97] you can optimize the amount of memory decreasing the code by 97 (if you know the input is going to be characters only) you also need to be aware what to do with capital characters ( are you conciser them as different or not) also in this case you need to take care to decrease the character by 65.

So at the end code would look like this:

```
int counts[122 - 97] = {0}; // codes of a - z
char a = get_next_char();
if ( is_capital(a)){
    counts[a - 65]++;
}
else 
{
    counts[a - 97] ++;
}
```

this code assumes the 'A' = 'a'
if its not the case you need to have different translation in the if's but you can probably figure out the idea now. This saves a lot of comparing as opposed to your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether the objective is CPU efficiency, memory efficiency, or developer efficiency, you could just do:

```
foreach(var grp in theString.GroupBy(c => c)) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
}
```

Not awesome efficiency, but fine for virtually on non-pathological scenarios. In real scenarios, due to unicode, I'd probably use a dictionary as a counter - unicode is to big to pre-allocate an array.

```
Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();
foreach(char c in theString) {
    int count;
    if(!counts.TryGetValue(c, out count)) count = 0;
    counts[c] = count + 1;
}
foreach(var pair in counts) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Dictionary<string, int>`, then iterate through array, check if element exist as key in dictionary and increment value.

```
Dictionary<string, int> counter = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if(counter.ContainsKey(item))
    {
        counter[item] = counter[item] + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will result in an empty dictionary, no?

Comment: Yes, but this was just idea how to resolve the problem. You can add else statement like this 
`else
{
    counter[item] = 1;
}`
@MarcGravell

Answer (score 0):

Here is wonderful example given, it may resolve your query.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-find

```
string[] array1 = { "cat", "dog", "carrot", "bird" };</br>
//
// Find first element starting with substring.
//
string value1 = Array.Find(array1,
    element => element.StartsWith("car", StringComparison.Ordinal));</br>
//
// Find first element of three characters length.
//
string value2 = Array.Find(array1,
    element => element.Length == 3);
//
// Find all elements not greater than four letters long.
//
string[] array2 = Array.FindAll(array1,
    element => element.Length <= 4);

Console.WriteLine(value1);
Console.WriteLine(value2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", array2));
```